# Android Studio test for libraries

Tags: junit, android-studio, robotium, android-espresso

I'm new on testing, I read some pages on testing for Android. I can't find pages for testing libraries on Android Studio.

My problem is to test a class without activity and with some private methods.

Someone know how to test libraries on Android Studio 1.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty broad question but if you're new to testing on Android take a look at: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html
This is mostly on how to test elements in Android, like activities and such.

Testing encapsulated methods and classes can be a pain, especially if it's stuff like libraries, but take a look at this (option 4): http://blog.octo.com/en/android-testing-testing-private-methods/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have found the two links. The second one is very interesting, but I think I can't test my methods because they are void methods and private. I don't know how to test a void method.

Comment: @DavidCesarSantos You could use reflection (as explained in option 3), and override the void methods, but I don't know if this will be a better solution for you.

Comment: I don't know if I will have a better solution. I just have void methods. But I just know assert to test. And, I can't use it with void methods. All this is a bit confusing for me.